# jQuery - Stop delay fadeOut by another event

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, settimeout, delay, fadeout

This is my current code. It works but when running another event (by clicking a button for example) I need it to stop and reset the fadeOut.

**Code**

```
$('#selector').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
```

- I have read that I need to use `animate` or `setTimeOut` instead of `delay`?
- What is the best way of doing this?

**Example**

In my case I have a statusbar on the top of the screen which is not going to fade away if I click something that updates the statusbar.

Comment: once you `fadeOut` is stopped, should be forever? some times you may want to stop a custom tooltip from fading out while you hover it, but it should fade out once the mouse is away for instance

Comment: @JFK It should not be forever. It should stop and reset just like your case with the tooltip. In my case I have a statusbar on the top of the screen which is not going to fade away if I click something that updates the statusbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reset the timer**

This is called before setting the timer. It prevents the timer to finnish if I click around like crazy. It stops and resets the timer.

```
clearTimeout(my_timer);
```

**Set the timer**

```
my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#selector').fadeOut('slow');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply call the `.stop()` method on the fading element: (`#selector2` is the button to stop the fade)

```
$('#selector2').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#selector').stop();
    }
);
```

Comment: `delay` cannot be cancelled by `stop`.

Comment: @AlexP. are you sure? seemed like it works for me

Comment: `stop` worked fine for me for implementing a simple tooltip with JQuery, on Chrome & Firefox

Answer (score 0):

see the function clearQueue()
https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/